# T460 Trackpoint Stops Working

Tags: trackpoint

I have an issue where the TrackPoint on my Lenovo T460 will work for a few minutes before it completely stops working. When it happens, the mouse will begin to lag/stutter for a few seconds.

I am running Kubuntu 19.10 and have xinput version 1.6.3 installed.

I have installed synaptics as suggested by multiple sources.

The device is still shown when using `xinput -list`

I have tried disabling/enabling.

The one POSSIBLE reason is the replacement keyboard I installed, but like I said - the device is still there.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add a little more information? Which version are you using? What desktop environment?

Comment: Edited to include - I am running Kubuntu 19.10 and have xinput version 1.6.3 installed

Comment: Did it always do this or did the problem start after a) adding the new keyboard; or b) installing synaptics, etc?

Comment: Honestly, it's been quite a while since it started acting like this so I'm not sure if the keyboard is the issue. I am trying to rule out software first. Installing synaptics was an attempt to fix the issue.

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 19.10 like you, on a ThinkPad T460, with no issues I've ever noticed. My trackpoint works ok, if it's any help.